# Styling special svelte elements

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I know this seems basic, but I have a svelte:component I'd like to be able to style, but can't find anything in the Svelte documentation that tells me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<svelte:component />` is kind of a virtual element, it won't have a corresponding element in the finally rendered DOM. So you can't style it.